# How to get result values of AJAX result using Select2 jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can you help me with this?
I am building an autocomplete ajax dropdown in my form and I have a problem in getting the result of the plugin. I have my ajax result but my problem is I can't display the result in a dropdown.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="product-selector" style="width:100%"></select>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#product-selector").select2({
        placeholder: "Please select product",
        ajax: {
            url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getProductBySelection&token=<?php echo $token; ?>",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function(params) {
               return {
                   q: params.term, // search term
                   page: params.page,
                   seller_id: <?php echo $seller_id; ?>
               };
            },
            processResults: function(data, page) {
                var results = [];

                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    results.push({
                        product_id: item.product_id,
                        name: item.name
                    });
                });

                return {
                    results: results
                };

                //console.log(results)

            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1
    });
</script>
```

And my output in the network tab is something like this:

```
[{"product_id":"45","name":"MacBook Pro"},{"product_id":"52","name":"sample3"},{"product_id":"56","name":"sample71"},{"product_id":"72","name":"Sample 45"}]
```

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think error is here? There isn't even variable with name `b`

Comment: When I checked where the error came from it goes to the js file of the plugin. And not in my code.

Comment: Does it minified? Try to include source file without minification and debug

Comment: Ok I manage to fix the error but my next problem is I can't put the output in the dropdown

Comment: As i know, `results` expects array with objects properties `id` and `text` (you pass `product_id` and `name`). Other way, you could provide `templateResult` function where you could define your own output format (there is nice examples https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your parameters as 'id' and 'text' rather than product_id and name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#product-selector").select2({
    placeholder: "Please select product",
    ajax: {
        url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getProductBySelection&token=<?php echo $token; ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        data: function(params) {
           return {
               q: params.term, // search term
               page: params.page,
               seller_id: <?php echo $seller_id; ?>
           };
        },
        processResults: function(data, page) {
            var results = [];

            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                results.push({
                    id: item.product_id,
                    text: item.name
                });
            });

            return {
                results: results
            };

            //console.log(results)

        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1
});
</script>
```

Read this documentation for [select2 4.0.0](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html)